Unable retrieve user Data from realtime database firebase in flutter dart
I am unable to retrieve user data such as name from my firebase real time database. My datasnapshot at this line is always null so it fails the next check.
var dataSnapshot = await _dbRef.child(_user!.uid).once();

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';
import 'package:firebase_database/firebase_database.dart';
import 'package:image_picker/image_picker.dart';
import 'dart:io';
import 'package:firebase_storage/firebase_storage.dart';

class MyProfilePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyProfilePageState createState() => _MyProfilePageState();
}

class _MyProfilePageState extends State<MyProfilePage> {
  final FirebaseAuth _auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;
  final DatabaseReference _dbRef = FirebaseDatabase.instance.reference().child("profile_image");
  final FirebaseStorage _storage = FirebaseStorage.instance;

  User? _user;
  String _email = '';
  String _name = '';
  String _profileImageUrl = '';

  final ImagePicker _imagePicker = ImagePicker();

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _getUserData();
  }

  void _getUserData() async {
    _user = _auth.currentUser;
    if (_user != null) {
      setState(() {
        _email = _user!.email ?? '';
        print(_email); // not email, it should be _email
      });
      var dataSnapshot = await _dbRef.child(_user!.uid).once();
      print(dataSnapshot); // not dataSnapshop, it should be dataSnapshot
      var userData = dataSnapshot.snapshot.value;
      print(userData);
      if (userData != null) {
        Map<dynamic, dynamic> userDataMap = userData as Map<dynamic, dynamic>;
        setState(() {
          _name = userDataMap['name'] ?? '';
          print(_name);
          _profileImageUrl = userDataMap['profileImageUrl'] ?? '';
          print(_profileImageUrl);
        });
      } else {
        // Handle the case where userData is null
        print('No user data found');
      }
    }
  }

I am trying to retrieve user details for profile page from RealTime Database, but this line is always null. I have added a screenshot of my database too.

The code looks fine at first glance. Please edit your question to show the data from the database that you expect thos code to load (as text, no screenshots please). You can get this by clicking the "Export JSON" link in the overflow menu (⠇) on your Firebase Database console. --- Also add print(_user!.uid) just before loading that data from the database, and make sure your question shows the updated code and its output - so that we can compare the UID to what is in the JSON that you're also adding.
